# Create the simplest allocator with two template arguments

Tags: c++, memory-management

I'm extremely new to C++ memory management, but want to make my hands dirty building a simple allocator that would preallocate in advance enough memory for some container.

I've looked at Alexandrescu Loki library and tried to read some blogs, but all this was just to diffucult for me to grasp. I want to start from some primitive and working starting point, expand it and see how it evolves. This is what I have now and what I do understand (my starting point):

```
template <class T>
struct Allocator {

    Allocator(){};

    template <class U>
    Allocator(Allocator<U> const&);

    T* allocate(size_t s) {
        return static_cast<T*>(::operator new(s * sizeof(T)));
    }

    void deallocate(T* p, size_t s) {
        ::operator delete(p);
    }

    void construct(T* p, T const& val) {
        ::new((void *)p) T(val);
    }

    void destroy(T* p) {
        return ((T *) p)->~T();
    }

    using value_type = T;

};
```

So, I can now use it like so:

```
std::vector<int, Allocator<int> > vec;
```

This allocator is very simple and I understand what it does. I now want to expand it a little bit, so that my client code would look like:

```
std::vector<int, Allocator<int, 8> > vec;
```

I would now expect my code to allocate enough memory for 8 elements. I tried to expand my starting code with these lines:

```
template <class T, size_t T_num_els>
struct Allocator {

    template <class U, size_t U_num_els>
    Allocator(Allocator<U, U_num_els> const&);

    ... I keep all the rest without changes just for testing reason
```

but when I compile it, I get a crazy list of error messages, some messages tell about required substitution, rebind_alloc and no type named "type". So, how can I fix it. What correction should I make to my stepping stone code to allow my allocator have two template parameters?

Comment: See [`std::allocator_traits`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator_traits) - that's how containers interrogate their allocators to discover their properties. The built-in implementation has some reasonable defaults for a) allocators of the form `template <typename T> class MyAllocator;`, and b) allocators that provide certain typedefs and member functions. Your `Allocator` no longer matches the pattern (a), so you can either guide built-in `std::allocator_traits` by providing those methods and typedefs, or specialize it for your class.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on this a little bit? A teeny-weeny example that would demonstrate usage of `allocator_traits` and a primitive allocator with two arbitrary template parameters - would be great! I would definitely accept it!

Comment: Adding a `rebind` helper seems to be sufficient for the big three compilers. As in `template <typename U> struct rebind { using other = Allocator<U, T_num_els>; };`

Answer (score 4):

I think the problem is that you have a non-type template parameter. The [`allocator_traits` adaptor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator_traits) does not seem to support that.

Some containers, like `std::list<int>`, will not allocate `int`s but some `internal_node<int>`. So it has to be able to transform an `Allocator<int>` into an `Allocator<internal_node<int>>`.

To create an allocator for such a type T, `allocator_traits` expects to either be able to do `Alloc::rebind<T>::other` from the original (C++98) allocator interface, or to use `Alloc<T, Args...>` when your allocator is `Alloc<U, Args...>`.

Neither of these two options match what can be done with your `Allocator`. The last one fails because the value `8` isn't a type that can match `Args`.

*Possibly* you can fix this by adding

```
template<class U>
struct rebind
{
   using other = Allocator<U, T_num_els>;
};
```

Comment: Thanks! I will check it in a minute!

Comment: Lifesaver, you can use `std::integral_constant<int, N>` as well.