# Usage of alignas in template argument of std::vector

Tags: c++, memory, stdvector, memory-alignment, avx2

I want to create a `std::vector` with doubles. But these doubles should be aligned in 32 byte for AVX2 registers. What would be the best way to do this? Can I simply write something like

`std::vector<alignas(32)double>`?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `alignas(32)double` compiled, it would require that *each* element separately had 32-byte alignment, i.e. pad each double out to 32 bytes, completely defeating SIMD.  (I don't think it will compile, but similar things with GNU C `typedef double da __attribute__((aligned(32)))` do compile that way, with `sizeof(da) == 32`.)

**See [Modern approach to making std::vector allocate aligned memory](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60169819) for working code.**

As of C++17, `std::vector<__m256d>` would work, but is usually not what you want because it makes scalar access a pain.

C++ sucks for this in my experience, although there might be a standard (or Boost) allocator that takes an over-alignment you can use as the second (usually defaulted) template param.

`std::vector<double, some_aligned_allocator<32> >` still isn't type-compatible with normal `std::vector`, which makes sense because any function that might reallocated it has to maintain alignment.  But unfortunately that makes it not type-compatible even for passing to functions that only want read-only access to a `std::vector` of `double` elements.

---

#### Cost of misalignment

For a lot of cases the misalignment is only a couple percent worse than aligned, for AVX/AVX2 loops over an array if data's coming from L3 cache or RAM (on recent Intel CPUs); only with 64-byte vectors do you get a significantly bigger penalty (like 15% or so even when memory bandwidth is still the bottleneck.)  You'd hope that the CPU core would have time to deal with it and keep the same number of outstanding off-core transactions in flight. But it doesn't.

For data hot in L1d, misalignment could hurt more even with 32-byte vectors.

In x86-64 code, `alignof(max_align_t)` is 16 on mainstream C++ implementations, so in practice even a `vector<double>` will end up aligned by 16 at least because the underlying allocator used by `new` always aligns at least that much.  But that's very often an odd multiple of 16, at least on GNU/Linux.  Glibc's allocator (also used by malloc) for large allocations uses `mmap` to get a whole range of pages, but it reserves the first 16 bytes for bookkeeping info.  This is unfortunate for AVX and AVX-512 because it means your arrays are always misaligned unless you used aligned allocations.  ([How to solve the 32-byte-alignment issue for AVX load/store operations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32612190/how-to-solve-the-32-byte-alignment-issue-for-avx-load-store-operations))

---

Mainstream `std::vector` implementations are also inefficient when they have to grow: C++ doesn't provide a `realloc` equivalent that's compatible with new/delete, so it always has to allocate more space and copy to the start.  Never even trying to allocate more space contiguous with the existing mapping (which would be safe even for non-trivially-copyable types), and not using implementation-specific tricks like [Linux `mremap`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mremap.2.html) to map the same physical pages to a different virtual address without having to copy all those mega/gigabytes.  The fact that C++ allows code to redefine `operator new` means library implementations of std::vector can't just use a better allocator, either.  All of this is a non-problem if you `.reserve` the size you're going to need, but it is pretty dumb.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Sounds like that I need to live with unaligned memory in a vector. Do you have any other ideas how to use aligned load from a vector? Or is it easier to use unaligned load and just live with the lower performance?

Comment: @vydesaster: As [Modern approach to making std::vector allocate aligned memory](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60169819) explains, there *are* ways to do it.  See also [How to solve the 32-byte-alignment issue for AVX load/store operations?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32612190) for allocation other than in `std::vector`, if you don't want `vector<__m256d>` or `vector<aligned_something, double>`.

Comment: But anyway, for a lot of cases the misalignment is only a couple percent worse looping over an array if data's coming from L3 cache (on recent Intel CPUs); only with 64-byte vectors do you get a significantly bigger penalty (like 15% or so even when memory bandwidth is still the bottleneck, so you'd hope that the CPU core would have time to deal with it and keep the same number of outstanding off-core transactions in flight.  But it doesn't.)  For data hot in L1d, misalignment could hurt more.