# AVX2 SIMD Segfault when loading

Tags: c++, c++20, simd, memory-alignment, avx2

Running

```cpp
template<SumAlgorithm algorithm_t, typename iterator_t, typename sum_t = typename std::iterator_traits<iterator_t>::value_type>
    sum_t avx2_sum(iterator_t begin,  iterator_t end) noexcept requires std::is_same<sum_t, float>::value && (algorithm_t == SumAlgorithm::Normal) {
        // SIMD-parallel summation stage
        auto running_sums = _mm256_set1_ps(0);
        long iterator_skip = 256/(8*sizeof(sum_t));
        for (; begin < end; begin += iterator_skip){
            std::cout << "HERE\n";
            __m256 tmp = _mm256_load_ps(begin);
            running_sums = _mm256_add_ps(tmp, running_sums);
        }

        // Serial summation
        running_sums = _mm256_add_ps(running_sums, _mm256_permute2f128_ps(running_sums, running_sums, 1));
        running_sums = _mm256_hadd_ps(running_sums, running_sums);
        running_sums = _mm256_hadd_ps(running_sums, running_sums);
        return _mm256_cvtss_f32(running_sums);
    }
```

like so

```cpp
constexpr unsigned int num_elements = 4096*4096;
constexpr unsigned int alignment = 32;
alignas(alignment) std::vector<float> float_vec(num_elements, 1.0);
std::cout << "avx2<float, Normal>: " << accumulators::avx2_sum<algo::Normal>(&(*float_vec.begin()), &(*float_vec.end())) <<"\n";
```

segfaults at the first run of the loop during _mm256_load_ps. When I dereference begin, it is validly 1.0... I aligned the vector all the floats come from, why does this segfault? Any ideas?

**Edit**
solution: as Peter Cordes said alignas only aligns the control block for the vector. used:[Modern approach to making std::vector allocate aligned memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60169819/modern-approach-to-making-stdvector-allocate-aligned-memory)

Comment: `alignas(alignment) std::vector` aligns the control block, not the memory pointed-to by the `.data()` member.  It's unfortunately a lot less convenient to get `std::vector<float>` to align the data.  It's easy with `std::vector<__m256>` in C++17 and later, but then you're stuck with a SIMD type throughout your program.

Comment: BTW, this is a good [mcve] for your alignment bug because it's compact, but not very efficient: in practice you'd want to unroll with multiple accumulators to hide FP add latency.  ([Latency bounds and throughput bounds for processors for operations that must occur in sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63095394) / [Why does mulss take only 3 cycles on Haswell, different from Agner's instruction tables? (Unrolling FP loops with multiple accumulators)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45113527)). Also, use a more efficient hsum; use 128-bit after vextractf128, and `hadd_ps` is more than 2 uops.