# A way to ensure std::vector is always aligned for optimal SIMD execution?

Tags: c++, optimization, c++17, stdvector, simd

I want to have X amount of std::vectors of equal size, which I can be processed together in a for loop which goes from start to finish in a linear fashion. For example:

```
for (int i = 0; i < vector_length; i++)
    vector1[i] = vector2[i] + vector3[i] * vector4[i];
```

I want all this to take full advantage of SIMD instructions. For this to happen, the compiler should be able to assume that each of the vectors are aligned optimally for __m256 use. If the compiler can't assume this, all sorts of non-optimal loops can be generated and used in the code.

How do I ensure this optimal alignment of std::vectors and optimal code generation for such aligned data?

It can be assumed that each vector has identical data structures inside, which can be added/multiplied together using standard SIMD instructions.

I'm using C++17.

MORE INFORMATION AS REQUESTED BY THE PEOPLE HERE:

32 bytes of alignment is good for my use.

I want to get this running on Intel Macs and PCs. (Xcode + Visual Studio) and later on ARM CPU Macs when I get one of those computers (Xcode again).

Comment: _"How do I ensure this optimal alignment"_ write a custom allocator. _"optimal code generation"_ you will need to provide details of your architecture and compiler.

Comment: In addition to the custom allocator, use `__assume(...);` (or your compiler's equivalent, or `[[assume(...)]];` in modern C++) to convince the compiler that the memory is sufficiently aligned.

Comment: How much alignment do you need? 32 bytes?

Comment: 32 bytes of alignment is great for my purpose.

Comment: The __assume(...); directive probably doesn't actually affect the std::vector's memory allocation itself, but only the algorithm which uses it, so the algorithm assumes the programmer has ensured already the alignment of the memory address? That being, said, all standard heap memory allocations can probably be assumed to be aligned at 32 bytes anyway?

Comment: There's a [memory-alignment] tag which applies, but the 5 existing tags are all relevant, too.  SO's tag limit should be raised to at least 8.  :/

Comment: *all standard heap memory allocations can probably be assumed to be aligned at 32 bytes anyway?* Definitely not.  For large allocations, glibc `malloc` / `new` allocate fresh pages from the OS, and reserve the first 16 bytes for bookkeeping, so you get a pointer such that `p % 4096 == 16`, aligned by `alignof(maxalign_t)` but misaligned by every higher power of 2.  And yes, this sucks since AVX is common, and AVX-512 actually cares significantly about alignment (unlike current CPUs with 256-bit vectors).  So you need to jump through hoops if you want to use common containers like std::vector

Comment: `std::vector<__m256>` would work in C++17, but only if *all* your uses for it are SIMD.  It makes scalar access inconvenient (it might be strict-aliasing safe in GCC to point a `float*` into a `__m256` which has float elements, but it's definitely not safe to point an `int*` into a `__m256i` which has `long long` elements.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Modern approach to making std::vector allocate aligned memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60169819/modern-approach-to-making-stdvector-allocate-aligned-memory)

Comment: Please don't add your solution to the question. Post it as an "answer" below instead. Then perhaps press the checkmark next to it to mark your question as solved. Also, when replying to comments, add `@username` to send a notification.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat OK, will do. I can only accept my own answer in two days, as Stackoverlow seems to prevent myself accepting my own answers sooner than that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As couple of people pointed out, there's a related question which can be used to first ensure properly aligned memory owned by the `std::vector`:

[Modern approach to making std::vector allocate aligned memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60169819/modern-approach-to-making-stdvector-allocate-aligned-memory)

That combined with `__attribute__((aligned(ALIGNMENT_IN_BYTES)))` added to the method parameters (pointers) seems to do the trick. Example:

```
void Process(__attribute__((aligned(ALIGNMENT_IN_BYTES))) const uint8_t* p_source1,
             __attribute__((aligned(ALIGNMENT_IN_BYTES))) const uint8_t* p_source2,
             __attribute__((aligned(ALIGNMENT_IN_BYTES))) uint8_t*       p_destination,
             const int      count)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        p_destination[i] = p_source1[i] + p_source2[i];
}
```

That seems to compile nicely (checked in Godbolt) so the compiler clearly assumes it can simply use large registers to process the data with SIMD instructions.

Thank you everyone!

Answer (score 1):

The only way to control the allocation of std::vector is by replacing the allocator. Boost has an implementation that ensures alignment: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_84_0/doc/html/align/reference.html#align.reference.classes

Comment: Also related: [Modern approach to making std::vector allocate aligned memory](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60169819) has an example allocator that uses C++17 aligned `new`/`delete` functionality.

Comment: That combined with __attribute__((assume_aligned (MY_OWN_ALIGN_SIZE))) in parameters given to methods seems to do the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Is the size of the data known beforehand or are you using any buffers? Cause then you could just us a normal `array` with `alignas`.
And for using SIMD instruction - you could use `valarray`. That and vector both internally use `malloc` wich in turn is guaranteed to respect the types alignment.

So `std::vector<__m256i> mySIMDVector;` is aligned.

Comment: the data will be X amount of screen buffers, which depend on the screen resolution.